# Como criar uma máscara entre uma imagem em QML e um elemento de QtQuick

Tags: qt, qml

Como criar uma máscara entre uma imagem importada para QML (ex.: um ícone png, jpeg, svg, etc...), e um elemento de user interface no background (ex.: um rectangle)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar o OpacityMask do Qml.  Exemplo:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Image {
        id: bug
        source: "images/bug.jpg"
        sourceSize: Qt.size(parent.width, parent.height)
        smooth: true
        visible: false
    }

    Image {
        id: mask
        source: "images/butterfly.png"
        sourceSize: Qt.size(parent.width, parent.height)
        smooth: true
        visible: false
    }

    OpacityMask {
        anchors.fill: bug
        source: bug
        maskSource: mask
    }
}
```

Documentação:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-opacitymask.html